# Ethernet cable allows only certain connections (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

A curious internet issue - when I connect to the ethernet cable, 80% of the time it only allows connections from certain servers (e.g. Yandex, Google, kresy.pl, gov.pl are allowed but not CBC, BBC, VisitBritain.com, Washington Post, https://www.tanzania.go.tz, governemnt of russia website). Could this be the result of a damaged cable or some Windows firewall malfunctioning? Yet the behaviour is so precise - certain websites are allowed, others are not.

Only trace of a firewall are some components of McAfee.

Same behaviour across browsers: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Comment: No way a cable could cause this issue. That sounds like a firewall issue with either your ISP or country or some combo of the both.

Comment: What's your alternative to the Ethernet cable?

Answer (score 2):

An Ethernet cable will not cause this issue. Try another cable to be sure.

Then use a Packet Sniffer (Wire Shark will work) and look at outbound traffic and responses.

Then set your Windows 10 Firewall to Default Values and restart the computer

Check at that point.

If you still have issues, access the Router, look at its firewall and look for websites it is blocking.

You might also consider resetting the Router to Factory specs, update the firmware and set it up again.

Good luck with this.